# AS3: How to control which MovieClip is displayed over which

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, flash-cs6

I'm making a game, in which some enemies are spawned in the right side of the screen, and then moving towards the left side of the screen. To get a little variation, the enemies are randomly spawned a little bit differently on the y-axis.

the problem:
So I'm aware, that the last added MovieClip gets displayed on top of the other MovieClips. But I need a method, so that no matter what time it was added, the MovieClip that is lower on the y-axis always gets displayed on top of MovieClips that are higher on the y-axis.
The reason is that otherwise it messes with the illusion of horizont in the game, since the MovieClips higher on the y-axis is supposed to look as if they are further away, than MovieClips lower on the y-axis.

I hope I'm making sense. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort them all based off of the `y` position, then set their index in the parent based off the sort order:

This function will take all the children of a container/parent, and sort them based off the `y` position.

```
function sortAllZ(container:DisplayObjectContainer):void {
    //build an array of all the objects:
    var list:Vector.<DisplayObject> = new Vector.<DisplayObject>();
    var i:int = container.numChildren;
    while(i--){
        list.push(container.getChildAt(i));
    }

    list.sort(sortZ);

    for(var i:int=0;i<list.length;i++){
        container.addChild(list[i]);
    }
}

function sortZ(a:DisplayObject, b:DisplayObject):Number {
    return a.y - b.y;
}
```

Since you'll likely be running this code every frame (assuming the y position of your objects changes over time), it would be more efficient to keep an array/vector of all your objects you want sorted. (instead of recreating a new one everytime you want to sort).  If that's the case, you can just do:

```
//where list is your vector/array, and container is the parent of items
function sortAll(){
    //sort the vector/array using the custom sort method defined below
    list.sort(sortZ);

    //now loop through that array and add the children in that order
    for(var i:int=0;i<list.length;i++){
        container.addChild(list[i]);
    }
}

//if you are using an array and not a vector, take out the :DisplayObject type declarations
function sortZ(a:DisplayObject, b:DisplayObject):Number {
    return a.y - b.y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!